# if $A, B$ are open in $\mathbb R$ then so is $A+B.$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to find out a counterexample to the problem:

if $A, B$ are open in $\mathbb R$ then so is $A+B.$

But I could not find any such counterexample. Please help me.

Comment: Do you consider the empty set and $\mathbb{R}$ to be open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you considered $a,b$ both interior points?  One an interior point and one a boundary point?  Both boundary points?  What did you find out?  (Have you drawn a picture?  The absence of pictures is a feature of the finished product, not a feature of arriving at that product.)

Comment: Yes I know they are open

Comment: @EricTowers *Boundary* points seem irrelevant here.

Comment: @Did:  Amusingly, you proved otherwise in your answer.  (I.e., you can't have any, which is very relevant.)

Comment: @EricTowers ?? What?

Answer (score 7):

Note that

$$
A + B = \bigcup_{a \in A} (a + B).
$$

Also note that $a + B$ is open if $B$ is. Why does this help you?

Answer (score 2):

No wonder you could not:

If $x$ is in $A+B$ then there exists $a$ in $A$ and $b$ in $B$ such that $x=a+b$. Since $A$ and $B$ are open (in a metric space), there exists $r\gt0$ such that $B(a,r)\subseteq A$ and $B(b,r)\subseteq B$. Can you prove that $B(x,s)\subseteq A+B$ for some suitable $s\gt0$?

Hence $A+B$ is open.