# Show that $A + B$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show in $\mathbb R^n$ given an open set $A$ and a non empty set $B$ that $A + B$ is open.
Do I show for $B$ being an open set (which would be trivial) and a closed set?

Comment: Is $+$ the element-wise sum?

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847149/if-a-b-are-open-in-mathbb-r-then-so-is-ab

Answer (score 7):

No. Arbitrary sets $B$ may be neither open nor closed.  Note that $A+\{b\}$ is open and write $A+B$ as union of open sets. Bonus: Where do you need that $B$ is non-empty? Do you really need it?

Comment: Many people assigning exercises (or even those giving definitions, e.g. symmetric groups only on *non-empty* sets...) assume that some sets are non-empty "just to be sure". I think they don't understand what's happening in these trivial cases and that they ignore the fact that often additional non-empty assumptions are not used at all, perhaps even misleading. Here is a great MO thread called "sexy vacuity": http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45951/sexy-vacuity

Comment: Thanks! So, in order to show that A + {b} is open, do I need to first show a ball B(b, epsilon) is in B?